# SwiftUI Drag gesture applies to parent view

Tags: swift, swiftui, gesture, drag

I have applied a drag gesture with some action to the Image views inside Foreach view, but when I drag an image - it visually drags all the images within the parent view and even in the other Foreach view with images. The action applied to the selected image works properly though. How can I make only selected image move and all others stay still?

Gesture variables:

```
@State var position = CGSize.zero
@GestureState private var dragOffset = CGSize.zero
```

There is the code:

```
ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach ((0..<player.playersCards.count), id: \.self) {number in
                        VStack {
                            Image(player.playersCards[number].pic)
                                .resizable()
                                .modifier(CardStyle())
                                .offset(dragOffset)
                                .gesture(
                                    DragGesture()
                                        .updating($dragOffset, body: { (value, state, transaction) in

                                            state = value.translation
                                        })
                                        .onEnded({ (value) in
                                            self.position.height += value.translation.height
                                            self.position.width += value.translation.width

                                            //player's turn
                                            
                                        })
                                )
                                .animation(.spring())

                            Text("\(ai.getPower(card: player.playersCards[number]))")
                                .modifier(TextModifier())
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s because all of your **images** in `forEach` are set to single `@GestureState` property, so when one is dragged all mapped to it gets dragged on **body** refresh. You can have separate `array` that store each drag state of your card at particular index uniquely.

```
struct LanguageView: View {


    @State var position = CGSize.zero
    @GestureState private var dragOffset:[CGSize]

    init() {
        let  dragOffsets = [CGSize](repeating: CGSize.zero, count: 5) // Initialise with your model array count
        _dragOffset = GestureState(wrappedValue: dragOffsets)
    }

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 5) {
                ForEach ((0..<5)) {number in
                    VStack {
                        Image("ABC")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 300, height: 100)
                            //.modifier(CardStyle())
                            .offset(dragOffset[number])
                            .gesture(
                                DragGesture()
                                    .updating($dragOffset, body: { (new, existing, transaction) in

                                        existing[number] = new.translation
                                    })
                                    .onEnded({ (value) in
                                        self.position.height += value.translation.height
                                        self.position.width += value.translation.width

                                        //player's turn

                                    })
                            )
                            .animation(.spring())

                        Text("Foo")
                        // .modifier(TextModifier())
                    }
                }
            }
        }.frame(width: 500, height: 100)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. The only issue I'm having now is the fact that card moves within the HStack area containing the cards and don't go over that area. Could you may be give an idea how to make it visually move over the whole screen or bigger area than a parent view?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define **number** for **playersCards** like you defined **pic** for that, it must start from 0 to your last card, then use this down code for drag

```
ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach ((0..<player.playersCards.count), id: \.self) {number in
                        VStack {
                            Image(player.playersCards[number].pic)
                                .resizable()
                                .modifier(CardStyle())
                                .offset(dragOffset)
                                .gesture(
                                    DragGesture()
                                        .updating($dragOffset, body: { (value, state, transaction) in
    
                                            if player.playersCards[number].number == number {     // <<: Here
                                                state = value.translation
                                            }
                                           
                                        })
                                        .onEnded({ (value) in
                                            
                                            if player.playersCards[number].number == number {    // <<: Here
                                                
                                                self.position.height += value.translation.height
                                                self.position.width += value.translation.width
                                                
                                            }
                                            
       
    
                                            //player's turn
                                            
                                        })
                                )
                                .animation(.spring())
    
                            Text("\(ai.getPower(card: player.playersCards[number]))")
                                .modifier(TextModifier())
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```